# When do I use a comma in this sentence?

Tags: commas

Would I use a comma as follows or not: `The challenging, technical race` or `The challenging technical race`

Comment: Are the words _technical_ and _race_ more closely bound than _challenging_ and _technical_? If so, omit the comma to show this. Compare sweet shop-girl and sweet-shop girl. Big hot dog and big, hot dog.

Comment: You may be interested in our sister site, [Ell.SE].

Comment: @EdwinAshworth but aren't `challenging` and `technical` adjectives, thus a comma must be places to show this?

Answer (score 1):

Though there is a previous related question, I'm going to use an answer here to utilise the formatting tools.

The rule is not as simple as 'place commas between all adjectives in a list', as this article at [Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/02/) explains:

.6. Use commas to separate two or more **coordinate adjectives** that describe the same noun. *Be sure never to add an extra comma between the final adjective and the noun itself or to use commas with non-coordinate adjectives.*

Coordinate adjectives are adjectives with equal ("co"-ordinate) status in describing the noun; neither adjective is subordinate to the other. You can decide if two adjectives in a row are coordinate by asking the following questions:

> 1. Does the sentence make sense if the adjectives are written in reverse order?
> 2. Does the sentence make sense if the adjectives are written with and between them?

If you answer yes to these questions, then the adjectives are coordinate and should be separated by a comma. Here are some examples of coordinate and non-coordinate adjectives:

> He was a difficult, stubborn child. (coordinate)
>
> They lived in a white frame house. (non-coordinate)
>
> She often wore a gray wool shawl. (non-coordinate)
>
> Your cousin has an easy, happy smile. (coordinate)
>
> The 1) relentless, 2) powerful 3) summer sun beat down on them. (1-2
>   are coordinate; 2-3 are non-coordinate.)
>
> The 1) relentless, 2) powerful, 3) oppressive sun beat down on them.
>   (Both 1-2 and 2-3 are coordinate.) >>

In OP's example, *challenging* (degree of dificulty qualifier) and *technical* (style identifier, or more probably domain specifier) are certainly not coordinate (having equal 'status' in describing the noun). In fact, as I hinted, 'technical race' may be close to ranking as a compound. You'd never put 'an exciting, three-legged race' or 'a chromium, steering wheel'.